# Why does my DropDownList display the data item type (System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem) instead of the data's value?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a drop-down-list which I'm populating with a `SelectList` filled with `SelectListItem` objects, but it's rendering the class names instead of the correct values. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

[image: wonky list]

Here is the code where I render the list:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedValue, @Model.RangeValues.SelectList)
```

The model is of type `DataParameterValuesModel`...

```
public class DataParameterValuesModel
{
    public string Description { get; set;}
    public DataRangesModel RangeValues { get; set; }
}

public class DataRangesModel
{
    public int? SelectedIdx { get; set; }
    public SelectList SelectList { get; set; }
}
```

And `SelectList` is populated with `SelectListItem` objects like this:

```
List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();

[...]

items.Add(new SelectListItem()
{
    Text = "whatever",
    Value = "whatever2"
});

[...]

parms.RangeValues = new DataRangesModel()
{
    SelectList = new SelectList(items),
    SelectedIdx = null
}
```

[image: wonky debug]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the 3rd constructor of `SelectList` and specify the data value field, and the data text field.

```
parms.RangeValues = new DataRangesModel()
{
    SelectList = new SelectList(items,"Value","Text"),
    SelectedIdx = null
}
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) the MSDN Reference